# Travis fails after renaming a swift class

Tags: swift, travis-ci

I was doing some refactoring on a Xcode Swift project. We had a spelling mistake in the name of a class which I corrected, both in the name of the class and in its declaration. Of course I changed every occurence as well.

The iOS projects builds and runs fine on my machine, but it does not on Travis. When I take a look into the travis logs I can see that the old file name is still in the build path – of course then it has to fail cause it won't be able to find that file.

Here's the .travis.yml

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode9.2
before_install:
- gem install cocoapods
- pod setup
- pod install
script:
    - export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
    - xcodebuild clean -project DQ-iOS-App.xcodeproj \
      -scheme DQ-iOS-App CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
    - xcodebuild -verbose -workspace "DQ-iOS-App.xcworkspace" \
      -scheme "DQ-iOS-App" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,\
      OS=11.2" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show build logs?

Comment: The crucial part imho was here:
`<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/travis/build/asseeger/DQ-iOS-App/DQ-iOS-App/Constant/FirabseFieldConstant.swift'`. The class name obviously was spelled incorrectly, so I had it changed to  `FirebaseFieldConstant.swift` which caused the issue on travis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to delete derrived data:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Comment: Did that, and now the build works... Don't quite understand why though, because when I push to github, the build process on travis gets started – what does this have to do with my local derived data?
Anyways, thanks a lot for your efforts!